# edge boundaries and morphological functions

Tags: c#

I am looking for some morphological functions and edge linking with c# corresponding to matlab functions.

Bw= binary image; operations look for

'clean'

Removes isolated pixels (individual 1s that are surrounded by 0s), such as the center pixel in this pattern

'skel'

With n = Inf, removes pixels on the boundaries of objects but does not allow objects to break apart. The pixels remaining make up the image skeleton. This option preserves the Euler number

if somebody knows some link or code , it would be helpfull regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can use this application/library:

- [Image Processing Lab in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/Image_Processing_Lab.aspx)

Image processing is a complex topic but a median filter may meet your needs.  If not, then this is at least a good framework to implement your own filtering algorithm.